# Display pages range in Barteksc PDFViewer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pdf

I'm using [barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) and  I want to load a page range between 15 to 25, but I'm fail to do it. Any one can help me how to display a range of pages starting at a chapter number from page 15 to page 25.

```
private void displayFromAsset(String assetFileName) {
pdfFileName = assetFileName;
pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)
        .defaultPage(15)
        .onPageChange(this)
        .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
        .onLoad(this)
        .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
        .load();
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `.pages()` attribute to your `pdfView`:

```
private void displayFromAsset(String assetFileName) {
int pageRange[] = new int[]{15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25};
pdfFileName = assetFileName;
pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)
        .defaultPage(15)
        .pages(pageRange)
        .onPageChange(this)
        .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
        .onLoad(this)
        .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
        .load();
}
```